# Debugging Watin Tests Runs Super Slow

Tags: resharper, watin, bdd

I'm using Watin and the tests run fine using Resharper test runner, but when I try and debug them they run but take forever!! Watin is wired up to use Internet Explorer.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  For me, the tests ran fast again when i switched the test project to build as x86 versus Any CPU.  I hope this helps you.